# Are sqlite PRAGMA settings permanent or do they "disapear" after DB close?

Tags: sqlite

I wonder if a PRAGMA statement such as eg.

PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF

"remains" in the db after the connection is closed, or if I have to set it each time opening the connection to the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not PRAGMA settings are permanent or not, depends upon the individual PRAGMA setting being used.

For example **journal_mode** in general is not permanent as per :-

> This pragma queries or sets the journal mode for databases associated
> with the current database connection.

However, setting **WAL** is persistent, setting the bytes at offset 18 and 19 to 2 in the database header file as per :-

> The WAL journaling mode uses a write-ahead log instead of a rollback
> journal to implement transactions. **The WAL journaling mode is
> persistent;** after being set it stays in effect across multiple
> database connections and after closing and reopening the database. A
> database in WAL journaling mode can only be accessed by SQLite version
> 3.7.0 (2010-07-21) or later.

[PRAGMA schema.journal_mode = DELETE | TRUNCATE | PERSIST | MEMORY | WAL | OFF](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode)

and as per

> 1.3.3. File format version numbers
>
> The file format write version and file format read version at offsets 18 and 19 are intended to allow
> for enhancements of the file format in future versions of SQLite. In
> current versions of SQLite, both of these values are 1 for rollback
> journalling modes and 2 for WAL journalling mode. If a version of
> SQLite coded to the current file format specification encounters a
> database file where the read version is 1 or 2 but the write version
> is greater than 2, then the database file must be treated as
> read-only. If a database file with a read version greater than 2 is
> encountered, then that database cannot be read or written.

[Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header)